# How to display the content in popup window?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Iam creating a button "SampleTest", which wil have to show the model data and "GoBack" button in popup window.But it displaying the content in full screen popup also overriding.Like,
[image]
i have my jquery like,

```
  $('#SampleTest').button().click(function () {
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/Dashboard/SampleTest/";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = function (data) {
            alert(data);
          $(".popup").html(data);
            $(".trasparentDiv").show(data);
            $(".popup").show(data);
             };
              $.ajax(options);
           });
```

Do i need to include any function in my jquery for popup window.Kindly tell me what to do in this case.

Comment: Are you expecting that `data-role="popup"` will magically generate a popup for you? That's not how HTML works... Or are you using some kind of framework that generates popups? If so, please post the code you're using to generate the popup.

Comment: Kindly refer the updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have rewritten the code like,

```
function LoadSampleTest() {
alert('sample');
$("<div></div>")
    .attr('id','SampleQuestionDiv')
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        title: "Sample Test"
    }).load("/dashboard/sampletest/");
```

Its works good.Instead of OK button, i have given close option to close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Please include JQuery UI script with appropriate version into your page after JQuery core script file.

Jquery UI CDN Path from JQuery: https://code.jquery.com/ui/

More help about Jquery Popup: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/